# Angular App running with ASP NET Web Api 2.2 on IIS

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2

I've encountered issue on my way to deploy Web Api 2.2 app on local IIS. The api has built in (inside wwwroot) compiled Angular app, and runs on my local IP, and that's how I want it to be. The problem is that when I try to get some data, for example angular tries to fill table using data fetched from API, I get such errors

[Angular Json error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djk8L.jpg)

This is how my service looks like, I belive this is the place where the error might be, so I am posting the code

```
export class SubscriptionService {

  url = 'http://192.168.0.103:80/api/subscriptions/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getSubscriptions(): Observable<Subscription[]> {
    return this.http.get<Subscription[]>(this.url);
  }
  GetSubscriptionById(Id: number): Observable<Subscription> {
    return this.http.get<Subscription>(this.url + Id);
  } 
  createSubscription(subscription: Subscription): Observable<Subscription> {
    const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
    return this.http.post<Subscription>(this.url ,
      subscription, httpOptions);
  }

  deleteSubscription(Id: number): Observable<number> {
    const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
    return this.http.delete<number>(this.url + Id,
      httpOptions);
  }



}
```

Do you have any experience with similar problems? I have more services within my Angular project, which looks basically the same, and with all of them I get the same error.

Comment: you are probably missing a rewrite rule for /api prefixed URIs. The response you receive seems to be the index.html of your angular frontend.

Comment: it seems the api is returning blank data..could you please check?

Comment: the problem is that you call to `api/subscription` return an error page or the own index.html. you need indicate to your Web API the router, in .NET Core is using app.useMcv, in others you need use config.Routes.MapHttpRouter, etc             NOTE. If you use httpClient it's NOT necesary add the header Content-type if you want send/get json objects

Comment: Well, deleting headers didn't change much. I've got app.UseMvc in my Startup configure method and in my controllers, just over the public class ControllerName I have [Route("api/[controller]")] [ApiController]. Of course all methods has corresponding headers : [HttpGet]

Comment: It concerns me even more, due to the fact that when I start web api from VS, and run ng serve on Angular project, they both work fine. Could you give me some more precise instructions ?

Comment: @Eliseo  Alright, problem has developed, I amended methods inside one of the services by addin responseType: 'text' as 'Json' line, and now error is different and says 
Error: Error trying to diff '<!doctype html> ... rest of index.html

Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: check the response